# PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in .NET Entity Framework

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-4

I am using Oracle 11 g with EDM (using ODP.net).  My Oracle SP returns a Ref Cursor and I am not able to run it from EDM. I have created a complex type and added function import for the SP selecting the return value as the complex type.

Once I run my application, I get the following error:

> ORA-06550: line 1, column 8:  PLS-00306: wrong number or types of
>   arguments in call to 'GetScriptDetail'.  ORA-06550: line 1, column 8: 
>   PL / SQL: Statement IGNORED

**My App.config :**

```
add name="SYSTEM.GetScriptDetail.RefCursor.cv_1" value="implicitRefCursor bindinfo='mode=Output'" 

add name="SYSTEM.GetScriptDetailbyAITID.RefCursorMetaData.cv_1.Column.0" value="implicitRefCursor metadata='ColumnName=TITLE;BaseColumnName=TITLE;NATIVEDATATYPE=Varchar2;ProviderType=Varchar2'"
```

**My Function Import contains** :

```
    public ObjectResult<GETSCRIPTDETAIL_Result> GETSCRIPTDETAIL(Nullable<global::System.Decimal> v_ID)
    {
        ObjectParameter v_IDParameter;
        if (v_ID.HasValue)
        {
            v_IDParameter = new ObjectParameter("V_ID", v_ID);
        }
        else
        {
            v_IDParameter = new ObjectParameter("V_ID", typeof(global::System.Decimal));
        }

        return base.ExecuteFunction<GETSCRIPTDETAIL_Result>("GETSCRIPTDETAIL", v_IDParameter);
    }
```

> It thorwing exception from "return
>   base.ExecuteFunction("GETSCRIPTDETAIL",
>   v_IDParameter);

My Oracle SP Parameter as:
    `v_ID IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL` ,

```
 cv_1 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
```

How can i pass refcursor output to executefuction as paramter ? or Do i required to pass this paramter ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the following in your .config file

```
<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
  <version number="*">
    <implicitRefCursor>
      <storedProcedure schema="schemaname" name="GETSCRIPTDETAIL">
        <refCursor name="CV_1">
          <bindInfo mode="Output" />
        </refCursor>
      </storedProcedure>
    </implicitRefCursor>
  </version>
</oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
```

I've found the steps here where you can do that semi automatically in VS directly:  http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/12c/r1/appdev/dotnet/EntityFrameworkOBE/EntityFrameworkOBE.html#section5

Now my problems are with the schema name being everywhere in the configuration and edmx, and I haven't found a decent way to make it dynamic.